# Divisor game cheating aid

Tags: python, primes

This code outputs the smallest number with more divisors than the input:

```
from operator import mul
from math import sqrt, ceil

def next_prime_factor(n):
    if n % 2 == 0:
        return 2
    for x in range(3, int(ceil(sqrt(n)) + 1), 2):
        if n % x == 0:
            return x
    return int(n)

def factor(n):
    factors=[]
    number=int(n)
    while number > 1:
                f=next_prime_factor(number)
                factors.append(f)
                number /= float(f)
                number=int(number)
                if number==1:break

    return list(factors)

def sundaram(max_n):
    numbers = range(3, max_n+1, 2)
    half = (max_n)/2
    initial = 4
    for step in xrange(3, max_n+1, 2):
        for i in xrange(initial, half, step):
            numbers[i-1] = 0
        initial += 2*(step+1)

        if initial > half:
            x=filter(None, numbers) + [2] if filter(None, numbers) != None else [2]
            return sorted(x)

def factor_count(n):
    factors=factor(n)
    primecounts=[]
    primes_list=sundaram(int(sqrt(n)))
    primes_list = primes_list if primes_list != None else [2]
    for i in primes_list:
        primecounts.append(factors.count(i))
    return primecounts

def div_exps(pcount):
    return [i+1 for i in pcount if i!=0]

def div_count(n):
    pcount=factor_count(n)
    div_count=reduce(mul,div_exps(pcount),1)
    return div_count

def next_num(last_num):
    if last_num == 1:
        return 2
    if last_num in sundaram(last_num+1):
        return 4

    plist=sundaram(int(sqrt(last_num))+1)

    div_count_factors=factor(div_count(last_num))
    num=1
    for i in enumerate(div_count_factors):
        num*=plist[i[0]]**(i[1]-1)

    end_num=num
    while 1:
        if div_count(end_num)<=div_count(last_num):
            end_num*=min(div_count_factors)
        else:
            break
    return end_num

ans=next_num(input('Input the last number chosen: '))
print 'The smallest number with more divisors than the inputted number is',ans,'.'
```

It was written to help <s>win</s> aid a number game.  The game is simple: somebody says a number, you say a number with more divisors than that number.

You get a point if your number is smaller.  So if Bob says "5", you can say "4" and get a point. The winner is first to 3 points.

This code outputs the next best number given the previous number as input.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Style guide

You should code your Python to follow PEP (*Python Enhancement Proposal*) documents, and in particular, PEP8.

## PEP8

Comparing your code to PEP8's standards shows *quite* a few violations.

- You should have whitespace between your binary operators.

> ```
> factors=[]
> number=int(n)
> ```

- Two blank lines after a declaration

> ```
> from operator import mul
> from math import sqrt, ceil
>
> def next_prime_factor(n):
> ```

- Comparison to `None`: instead of `!= None` it should be `is not None`

> ```
> x=filter(None, numbers) + [2] if filter(None, numbers) != None else [2]
> ```

- Line too long: PEP8 has a maximum character count of 79 characters per line, this line has 82:

> ```
> print 'The smallest number with more divisors than the inputted number is',ans,'.'
> ```

- `while 1` should be denoted as `while True` instead:

> ```
> while 1:
> ```

---

## Whitespace and naming

You have double indentation here:

> ```
> while number > 1:
>             f=next_prime_factor(number)
>             factors.append(f)
>             number /= float(f)
>             number=int(number)
>             if number==1:break
> ```

You should avoid names like this:

> ```
> numbers = range(3, max_n+1, 2)
> half = (max_n)/2
> ```

Their purpose is a little confusing. Try to use more descriptive names that better describe *what* they are.

You should name your variables like `snake_case`:

> ```
> primecounts
> ```

---

## Unnecessary logic

> ```
> div_count=reduce(mul,div_exps(pcount),1)
> return div_count
> ```

You're defining a variable right before returning it, just return it directly.

> ```
> for i in primes_list:
>     primecounts.append(factors.count(i))
> return v
> ```

You can use the list comprehension notation instead:

```
primecounts = [factors.count(i) for i in primes_list]
```

> ```
> if div_count(end_num)<=div_count(last_num):
>     end_num*=min(div_count_factors)
> else:
>     break
> ```

When you have a block that looks like this:

> ```
> if condition == true/false:
>     doSomething()
> else:
>     endBlock #return, break, continue
> ```

When the block terminates in the `else` loop, you can reverse the conditions and reduce a layer of logic:

> ```
> if condition != true/false:
>     endBlock
>
> doSomething()
> ```

So, you can simplify that above block down:

```
if div_count(end_num) > div_count(last_num):
    break

end_num *= min(div_count_factors)
```

The code after the `if` is not needed: `filter` always returns a list, which is empty, if no elements remain. This results in identical behavior to the current code.

> ```
> x=filter(None, numbers) + [2] if filter(None, numbers) != None else [2]
> ```

Comment: This helped the most so far, and is really what I wanted to get reviewed.  Thanks a lot.

Comment: And are list comphresions really good form?  I thought they were only useful in golfing.

Comment: @EasterlyIrk yeah, I use them in my non golfing code

Comment: @ Quill okay, cool.

Answer (score 1):

## You’ve got a bug

Well, I guess. Your lack of comments and/or docstrings make understanding `sundaram` and thus `factor_count` pretty hard. So I went for the description and the `factor` / `next_prime_factor` functions.

Anyway:

> ```
> $ python2 code.py 
> Input the last number chosen: 9
> The smallest number with more divisors than the inputted number is 12 .
> ```

I thought 8 had as much divisors than 12 and was smaller.

> ```
> $ python2 code.py 
> Input the last number chosen: 12
> The smallest number with more divisors than the inputted number is 36 .
> ```

Same here, 16 is 2×2×2×2, same lenght but smaller than 2×2×3×3.

So, either I didn’t understand things well and there is some special handling of redundant factors; or you need to take into account that \$2^n\$ is the smallest number with \$n\$ divisors.

With that in mind, you can remove almost anything except `factor` and `next_prime_factor`.

## Count factors, don't list them

Knowing that, in order to generate the smallest number with more than \$n\$ factors, you only need to compute \$2^{n+1}\$, there is no need in listing the factors of the input number. Just counting them should be enough:

```
def factors(n):
    number = int(n)
    count = 1

    while number > 1:
        number /= next_prime_factor(number)
        count += 1

    return count
```

Several things to note here:

- `if number==1:break` is useless since this case is already handled by `while number > 1`;
- `factors.append(f)` is not needed anymore since we just want to count factors;
- `number /= float(f)`: why do you want to perform floating-point division when you know for sure that `number % f` is 0 (you wrote `next_prime_factor` for that purpose);
- `number = int(number)` is thus not needed anymore.

I also renamed `factor` (which suggest an action) into `factors` (which suggest a query).

## `range`

Since you’re using Python 2, the `range` builtin will return a list. And since you’re calling `next_prime_factor` several times, it will build several lists while, often, only using the first few items from them.

As an example, lets assume the user entered 729 (aka \$3^6\$). `next_prime_factor` will thus be called 6 times returning 3 at each call. In the meantime, it will build 6 (useless) lists:

```
[3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21, 23, 25, 27]
[3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15]
[3, 5, 7, 9]
[3, 5]
[3]
[]
```

Instead, you should use `xrange` which will generate numbers when needed.

I can also advise you to look into the `yield` keyword to turn this function into a generator and avoid computing `ceil` and `sqrt` at each call.

## `input`

This function let Python interpret the user input for you. Meaning that if the user enters `86524` the returned value is an `int`; if `3.14` is entered the returned value is a `float`; and if `hello` is entered, the returned value is a `str`. So technicaly you do not need the various `int(n)` calls in your code.

However, `input` is deemed insecure for the exact same reason: Python interpret the user input. You should instead use the `raw_input` function which will always return strings and perform the desired convertion yourself, as you did using `int`. Note that, in Python 3, `raw_input` has been renamed `input` and the original `input` has been dropped.

## Proposed improvements

```
from math import sqrt, ceil


def next_prime_factor(number):
    if number % 2 == 0:
        return 2
    for divisor in xrange(3, int(ceil(sqrt(number)) + 1), 2):
        if number % divisor == 0:
            return divisor
    return number


def factors(number):
    count = 1

    while number > 1:
        number /= next_prime_factor(number)
        count += 1

    return count


def next_number(n):
    number = int(n)
    return 2**factors(number)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ans = next_number(raw_input('Input the last number chosen: '))
    print 'The smallest number with more divisors than the inputted number is', ans, '.'
```

You can read more about the last `if` in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/419163/5069029).

Comment: Actually, 16 has less *divisors* than 36.   So that isn't a bug.  But good answer!

Comment: @EasterlyIrk As said, I didn't quite get the code, so I assumed divisors was a shorthand for prime factors. Anyway, the first comment still apply: you need better description of what your code does.

Comment: Okay, I'll try.  Probably post a follow up question.

Comment: @EasterlyIrk 24 has more divisors than 12...